# "Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя такой, какая ты есть."

Tags: грамматика

Правильно ли построено предложение? Я сомневаюсь, но не знаю по какому правилу проверить.
*Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя такой, какая ты есть.*

Answer (score 1):

После редактирования: **Я должна принять твой вЫбор и   принять тебя такОй, какая ты Есть.**

В текст добавлен  еще один глагол ***принять***, также расставлены логические ударения.

В исходном виде предложение неудобно для чтения.

Comment: Два раза "принять"?


>> В исходном виде предложение неудобно для чтения.
В исправленном еще более неудобно.

Answer (score 1):

> Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя такой, какая ты есть.

**Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя — такой, какая есть.**

Тире введено как замещение подразумеваемого *принять*; местоимение *ты* можно опустить при наличии *твой* и *тебя*. Перед паузой напрашивается связка *тебя саму*: Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя саму — такой, какая есть.

Comment: Хороший вариант, только местоимение "ты" нужно оставить.

Comment: Хорошо-то хорошо, но на вопрос мы не ответили: по какому такому правилу? Правда, если это домашнее задание, то и не надо.

Comment: А там грамматика была некорректной. Союз И в вашем варианте соединяет дополнения "твой выбор и тебя, в моем варианте союз И соединяет  инфинитивы "принять твой выбор и принять тебя такой". А в заданном предложении союз соединяет дополнения "твой выбор и тебя такОй". А ведь местоимением ТАКОЙ  управляет глагол, и тогда соединительная связь получается НЕОДНОРОДНОЙ.  Да и грамматика  местоименной пары "твой - такой "на слух плохо определяется.

Comment: @shampar Нет, это не домашнее задание. Просто занимаюсь командным переводом, где я предложил отредактировать это предложение, а остальные отказались, вот и искал правило. В итоге выбрали вариант с двумя "принять", только первое заменили на "поддержать"

Comment: Домашнее по смыслу. И хотя задача сформулирована не прямо, смысл поняла Jasmin.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже склоняюсь к варианту ***Я должна принять твой выбор и тебя — такой, какая ты есть***.

Тире, однако здесь не является обязательным, вряд ли эта замена опущенному сказуемому - в том случае оно бы перед "тебя" стояло. Так что тире это здесь чисто интонационное, подчеркивающее акцент на "такой, какая есть".
Если бы основная нагрузка падала на слово "тебя" (случай менее вероятный, но возможный), то и тире было бы ненужным.

Answer (score 0):

Самый лучший синтаксис не спасет плохую семантику. Предложение нужно переделать - предлагаемые косметические меры не помогают.